# Android spinner item long click/touch

Tags: android, click, spinner

I have in my application spinner. I want to detect long click/touch on its items. I tried this:

```
    ipSpinner.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            System.out.println("long click on position: " + arg2);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

But this code doesn't work and I don't know why.

I need to detect long click because I want to enable to delete each items of spinner.
Is there another smart way to delete items?

Comment: Spinner does not support long click. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2732108/291827

Answer (score 0):

Spinner does not yet support Long Click as indicated by Jason Robinson.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a custom spinner class by extending spinner,

```
public class CCSpinner extends Spinner {
    public CCSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CCSpinner(Context context, int mode) {
        super(context, mode);
    }

    public CCSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CCSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public CCSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int mode) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, mode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    }
}
```

Use the above spinner in your xml view.

2) Define an interface to handle clicks,

```
 public interface ClickListener {
        void onItemLongClicked(View view);
        void onItemClicked(View view);
    }
```

3) In your spinner adapter class do these stuffs in getView and getDropDownView

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //ususal stuffs
        convertView.setTag(R.string.click_tag, position);
        convertView.setClickable(false);
        convertView.setLongClickable(false);



        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //ususal stuffs
        convertView.setTag(R.string.click_tag, position);

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onItemClicked(v);
                }
            }
        });


        convertView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                if (clickListener != null) {
                    clickListener.onItemLongClicked(v);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
```

4) While instantiating the adapter, pass the ClcikListener interface we created.

5) and in the implementing class do the following,

```
@Override
    public void onItemLongClicked(final View view) {
        mPSpinner.onDetachedFromWindow();
        final int pos = (int) view.getTag(R.string.click);
        mPSpinner.setSelection(pos);
    }


@Override
public void onItemClicked(final View view) {
    mPSpinner.onDetachedFromWindow();
    int pos = (int) view.getTag(R.string.click);
    mPSpinner.setSelection(pos);
}
```