# Android Spinner OnLongClickListener or OnItemLongClickListener

Tags: android, spinner

Anyone have a work around to get this set up? I have a spinner in my action bar where I'd like to capture a long click event, either OnLongClickListener, or for the individual item OnItemLongClickListener - so the user can edit the value.

I've read that spinner doesn't support long clicks, but I was hoping that something might have changed/someone might have a workaround.

It's the ideal solution for editing the string - there's not enough space in the action bar to put a dedicated button for editing, and my users intuitively try to long press to edit.

Here are some related questions (although quite old now):
[Android spinner item long click/touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050579/android-spinner-item-long-click-touch),
[How can I use spinner setOnItemLongClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730610/how-can-i-use-spinner-setonitemlongclicklistener)

Comment: make you're own spinner.  Make an image View and have it rotate with a long click listener on it

Comment: I think you mean like a loading icon? Android spinner is like a drop down list where you select an item - see here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Comment: ya your own loading icon if you want something you can click on.  Add an image view to your layout and put a longclicklistener on it

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm not asking about a loading icon - a spinner is actually a type of selector in android. Check out the link I posted

Comment: have you tried adding a long press listener to a layout containing the spinner?

Comment: @DaveS Hmm no I haven't, I'll give this a shot too, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @DaveS No luck, thanks anyways though!

Comment: You might be able to get it to work with these settings http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:descendantFocusability
Otherwise urudroid might have the best solution.

Comment: @DaveS I'll try those out - probably should try beforeDescendants, as blockDescendants will probably prevent the spinner from getting any focus?

Comment: Yea blockDescendants probably isn't what you want, beforeDescendants looks like the best choice for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to "simulate" a long click with the following code:

```
final Handler actionHandler = new Handler();
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "Long click performed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        spinner.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    actionHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
                } else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    actionHandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                }
                return false;

            }
        });
```

Yo can play around with the time in order to get a more "real" feeling, but that's pretty it i believe.

I hope it helps

Comment: This works! Thank you!!  Are there any drawbacks of using this method? Obviously launching extra threads is not entirely ideal, but how big of an issue is that really?

Comment: That's great! i can't think of any drawback right now. You just need to be careful with other events attached to the spinner

Comment: @mmmyum i think Handler will not create a thread, it will just add that runnable to the message queue of the thread you're in. See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

Comment: Yes you're right, just adds to the message queue! It's working great for me right now, I'll be careful with any other events I decide to attach later. Thanks again dude!