# Why does Android Studio code completion display methods which are not valid for the object?

Tags: android, code-completion, android-studio-2.3

I'm attempting to work with a Spinner control.  I have successfully implemented the `.setOnItemSelectedListener()` and I was attempting to implement the `.setOnItemLongClickListener()`.

I was led to believe the Spinner would support the `.setOnItemLongClickListener()` because I saw it Android Studio's code completion window (see image below).

I'm assuming Android Studio code completion uses reflection to examine the class and determine what methods are available.

Why doesn't Android Studio remove these methods which are actually unavailable on these sub-classes?

Maybe reflection sees these methods as available (since reflection knows this sub-class is-a <parent-class> and it assumes they are available) but it would be nice if Android Studio did some extra work to remove these before displaying.

Might this be considered a bug?  I'm thinking that Visual Studio is better at this with IntelliSense.

[image: Android Studio code completion]

Comment: What makes you think any of those methods are *not* available?

Comment: It's an AdapterView.... Those methods are definitely available. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html

Comment: App crashes when implementing some of those methods. For example, when I implemented setOnItemClickListener (which is in the code completion snapshot above) I get this in the Log :
java.lang.RuntimeException: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner.
Also Google docs show that only setOnItemSELECTEDListener is actually available on Spinner. See => https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html

Comment: @cricket_007 It's too bad you said those methods are _definitely_ available without researching it, because it is going to confuse others.  Those methods are not actually available on Spinner.  Please check and consider deleting your comment.

Comment: I urge you to expand the AdapterView Inherited methods on that page

Comment: I urge you to actually implement. :) The point is, you can see that the log itself actually warns that the one method is unavailable on a spinner.  That's android logging.  Also, I can indeed implement the setOnItemLongClick() method.  However, it is never actually fired.  I urge you to create a spinner and implement the longclick method and see. Also, there is a post on SO that mentions Spinners don't implement LongClick : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730610/how-can-i-use-spinner-setonitemlongclicklistener?noredirect=1&lq=1
Post is 7 years old and why I've been researching this.

Comment: You certainly have a lot of conviction raddevus. Here is a working Spinner with a long click listener https://i.imgur.com/qFOFgre.png There is not enough code shown in your question to see where you went wrong (unless it is that space in your call to `.setOn setOn`...). But I assure you that Spinners can have long click listeners.

Comment: @Stephen  Wait...What? You ran that code? Because if that code works you are the only one on SO and possibly the entire web who has gotten LongClick to work on a Spinner.  I will indeed try your code.
Also, I know you can actually implement it, but the code never fires. Plus, keep in mind that my original question was why are methods shown that aren't actually implemented and as my comment above shows, when you implement the setOnItemClickListener then the app will actually crash and write to the log that the method cannot be implemented on a spinner.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/YCaNmFl.png

Comment: Also, the names are so close together -- notice that I was originally talking about OnITEMLongClickListener.  I haven't tried OnLongClickListener.  I really appreciate your help though. Keep me honest here.  :)
Try OnITEMLongClickListener. See if it will ever fire.  I don't believe it will.  Very curious.

Comment: Ah, some of your question does refer to `setOnLongClickListener` so that threw me off. I also see that you are right that Spinner does not allow use of `OnItemLongClickListener` and throws an exception if you try.

Comment: @Stephen Thanks for trying that out and mentioning the same behavior as I saw.  Also, I tried OnLongClickListener and that does indeed work on my Spinner. Glad you pointed that out because now I'm wondering if I can determine the value that is currently selected (in Spinner) anyways and then the functionality I'm looking for will work.  Good discussion. Thanks.